# How can I get all the URL of the dependencies of a deb package?

Tags: apt, package-management

I want to check if it is possible to list the URL's that are needed for all the dependencies for a specified systems.

lets suppose i want to install a software and it depends on 100 + individual packages and i need to get a couple of tens of such packages. it happens that i am inside a restrictive proxy (hell!!! of course) that asks me to specify each URL that i need access to.

I figured out that i can use apt-rdepends to get a list of the dependent packages. but how do i get the dependencies correct to urls (assuming *.ubuntu.com is okay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use apt-get and the `--print-uris` option to show URI's:

```
sudo apt-get --print-uris install geany
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  geany-common
Suggested packages:
  libvte9
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  geany geany-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,242 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,894 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/geany/geany-common_1.22+dfsg-2ubuntu1_all.deb' geany-common_1.22+dfsg-2ubuntu1_all.deb 2153292 MD5Sum:e7dc7ca72d4e3b27ebfeadaea9fb3289
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/geany/geany_1.22+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb' geany_1.22+dfsg-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb 1089150 MD5Sum:e201bf70fc0ef23b0f64c410125814cb
```

This is the simplest method and without installing anything extra.

apt-get man excerpt:

```
--print-uris
       Instead of fetching the files to install their URIs are printed. Each URI will have the path, the
       destination file name, the size and the expected MD5 hash. Note that the file name to write to
       will not always match the file name on the remote site! This also works with the source and update
       commands. When used with the update command the MD5 and size are not included, and it is up to the
       user to decompress any compressed files. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Print-URIs.
```

Comment: can we list the same with out actually installing the packages?

Comment: Mmmm.. as you can see, I actually press `y` and it didn't installed. When you use `--print-uris` the only thing done is printing the URL's. No other action is performed.

Comment: It does not print anything if the package is already installed.

Comment: @peterh yeah, that's what the man page says "Instead of fetching the files to install their URIs are printed".